# Proper age restriction for facebook applications

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restriction

I have tried to implement the age restrictions by using a post request on the graph:

https://graph.facebook.com/[APP_ID]?restrictions={"age_distribution":"18+"}&method=post&access_token=[FUNKYFIED_ACCESS_TOKEN]

This sets the restriction to 18, however when a user hides the year when he/she was born the user will never pass the age restriction... I understand that the graph won't return the birthday when a user has hidden his/her birthday/birthyear. But why won't facebook allow the user through the restriction?

Is there any other method on doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your app could request the user's birthday in the permissions and you can do a calculation based on that but that just gives you the same problems - not everyone will have entered their DOB on Facebook.

Only other thing I can suggest is take a look at some other pages and see how they do it, some good examples might be the Fan pages of alcoholic beverages.

Comment: Fan pages have the option to restrict the whole page , i will do it with the users birthday ... sucks that user has to give permissions though! Thanx for the fast reaction

Comment: You HAVE to submit your birthday to facebook when you open an account.  Every user has a birthday entry for their user.

Comment: Thanks for the info Lix, wasn't sure because I've never had to use it but going from what I see on my friend's info sections not all of them have it publicly available.

Comment: It still does suck supreme... sigh

Comment: Ok, i've now used auth to ask for birthday permissions, request a real timestamp from a server (php script) otherwise you can circumvent the check by changing your local time ( sigh ) then get the me object of the current user (double sigh) do a double check if the birthday is filled ( since i ask for permissions on multiple places in the flow ( triple sigh ) then calculate the difference between the php timestamp and the currentbirthday and calculate the age ... Still, underaged users will see some content ( i like to use iframe oauth request ) hopefully it's legit here in the Netherlands